# Is my proof of 'If $G$ contains any odd permutations then precisely half of the elements of $G$ are odd' correct?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $G$ be a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$.Show that if $G$ contains any odd permutations then precisely half of the elements of $G$ are odd.

My proof:

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $S_n$, and partition $G$ into a group $A$ containing all even permutations of $G$ and a set $O$ containing all odd permutations of $G$.

If $\sigma \in G$ and $sgn(\sigma)=-1$, then $\forall a \in A$, we have $$sgn(a\sigma)=-sgn(a)$$ and hence $\sigma a \in O$.

Define function $f:A \to O$ by $$f(a)=\sigma a$$ Since $\sigma^{-1} \in G$, we have $$f^{-1}(x)=\sigma^{-1}x$$ and hence proved that $f$ is a bijection. Therefore $|O|=|A|$

Is this correct? Are there any logical mistakes?

Comment: Could someone please help? I am self-studying maths and problems without solution really make life difficult

Comment: Correct. This is the argument used on the way to proof of Lagrange's theorem. Any two cosets have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (your) argument is correct.

Note that if $G$ would have been whole $S_n$, then you will define a map from $G=S_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{1,-1\}$, $\sigma\mapsto sign(\sigma)$, and it is a homomorphism. Then kernel contains even permutations, its cardinality is half of $|G|$ and so remaining are half, and odd permutations.

This proof still works if $G$ is not necessarily $S_n$ but contains an odd permutation.