# Let $G \le S_n$ ,show that if $G$ has an odd permutation then half of the elements in $G$ are even permutation and the other half are odd permutation.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Assume $G \le S_n$ ,show that if $G$ has an odd permutation then half of the elements in $G$ are even permutation and the other half are odd permutation.   Moreover conclude that $G$ has a subgroup of index $2$.  I've seen the following related proof:

> Define a map  $\text{sgn}:S_n→\left\{−1,1\right\}$ which is given by:

> $$  \begin{align} \text{sgn(σ)} = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}                  1 & \hspace{5mm} \text{if σ is a product of an even number of >transpositions} \\                 -1 & \hspace{5mm} \text{if σ is a product of an odd number of transpositions} \\                 \end{array} \right. \end{align}$$

> Then the kernel of the mapping would be the alternating group $A_n$,by the isomorphism theorem $S_n/A_n≅\left\{−1,1\right\}$.

> Now by the Lagrange's  theorem  it  follows  that  $|A_n|= \frac{|S_n|}{2}.$

> This  means  that  exactly  half  of  the  permutations  in    Sn    are  even  and  so  exactly  half  are  also  odd.

But  I  don't  see  how  to  conclude  that  for    $G \le  S_n$  with  the  given  assumptions  the  claim  that  half  of the  elements  in  $G$  are  even  permutation  and  the  other  half  are  odd  permutation  does  hold. Maybe after  this  it  looks  straight  forward  but  can  someone $2$? show  me why $G$ has a subgroup of index

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866591/show-that-if-h-is-a-subgroup-of-s-n-then-either-every-member-of-h-is-even and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2437065/show-that-every-subgroup-of-s-n-has-either-every-member-as-even-or-exactly-hal and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539216/is-my-proof-of-if-g-contains-any-odd-permutations-then-precisely-half-of-the and probably half-a-dozen others.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*. Restrict $\mathrm{sgn}$ to a homomorphism $\mathrm{sgn}:G\to\{\pm1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if $\tau$ is an odd permutation in $G$, then the map $\sigma \mapsto \tau\sigma$ is a bijection $G \to G$ and it maps even permutations to odd ones and vice-versa.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/566083/589